# NSImageView becomes blurry when applying transformation

Tags: objective-c, calayer, nsimage

I have an NSImageView I'm applying a rotation to, like this:

```
NSImageView *imageView = [[NSImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,100,140)];
imageView.image = someImage; 
imageView.frameCenterRotation = -5;
```

Before I apply the rotation, the image image is crystal clear. After I apply the rotation, the image becomes a bit blurry and the edges especially seems very pixelated.

Is there anything I can do to make the edges less pixelated?

And please notice, this is a Mac app, not an iOS app.

Comment: You mean, UIImageView?

Comment: I see.  It's a Mac application, not an iOS application.  Yet, you had iOS tag.

Comment: @ElTomato No, I do mean NSImageView. Reason I also posted under iOS, is that a lot of iOS people have also done Mac stuff.